# Issue with "npx dapp-store validate"

Tags: dapp

My Android SDK build tools and JDK are from my Unity installation.

I have added the JAVA_HOME variable linking it to the JDK folder and added it to the paths as well. I have also tried downloading JDK17 from the Oracle site but the issue is the same.

In my .env file when I add the path to my build tools and run the command:

```
npx dapp-store validate -k <path_to_your_keypair>
```

I have this error:

```
There was an error parsing your APK. Please ensure you have installed Java and provided a valid Android tools directory containing AAPT2.                   │
   │   Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.17f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2/aapt2 dump badging    │
   │   "C:\Users\JayH1V2\Downloads\Unity\GIT\dinosurvivor_clean\Solana\publishing\Dino_with_a_Gun_Solana.apk"
```

When I remove the build tools path from my .env file and run the command again I have this error:

```
Publisher JSON valid!
App JSON valid!

   ┌─────────────────────────── Error ───────────────────────────┐
   │                                                             │
   │   Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'version')   │
   │                                                             │
   └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Not sure what is wrong. Anyone can advise, please?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the path to your android tools is correct in your .env file.
For me it looks like this:

```
ANDROID_TOOLS_DIR="/Users/jonasmac2/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/34.0.0"
```

Maybe you need version 34. The unity version seems to be 30.0.2/

You can check if java is correctly installed like so:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

Here is a video walkthrough in case you want to have a look:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgeE1mg1aYk&t=1s